# QGIS server connection times out when trying to reach the /wfs3/collections endpoint

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, docker, ogc-api, ogc-api-features

This is the landing page of a [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org) server instance ([camptocamp/qgis-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/camptocamp/qgis-server)) which connects to a containerized [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database to serve some vector data using the "[OGC API - Features](https://ogcapi.ogc.org/features/)" (aka WFS3) protocol:

[image: QGIS server landing page]

And this is what happens (after ~2 seconds only) when I try to reach `/wfs3/collections` by clicking on "Feature collections" with Firefox 94.0:

> The connection has timed out
>
> The server at my.server.org is taking too long to respond.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

the log of the `qgisserver` docker service are as following at that precise moment:

```
qgisserver_1  | 20:35:43 WARNING Server[81]: The client requested an unsupported content type in Accept header: */*
qgisserver_1  | 1726 - 10.193.23.169 - - [22/Nov/2021:20:35:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 254 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
qgisserver_1  | 20:35:43 WARNING Landing Page[81]: QGIS_SERVER_LANDING_PAGE_PROJECTS_DIRECTORIES empty path: skipping.
qgisserver_1  | 20:35:43 WARNING Landing Page[81]: QGIS_SERVER_LANDING_PAGE_PROJECTS_PG_CONNECTIONS empty connection: skipping.
qgisserver_1  | 8153 - 10.193.23.169 - - [22/Nov/2021:20:35:43 +0000] "GET /index.json HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
qgisserver_1  | 5312899 - 10.193.23.169 - - [22/Nov/2021:20:35:40 +0000] "GET /wfs3/collections HTTP/1.1" 200 2030 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
qgisserver_1  | 20:37:16 WARNING Server[81]: The client requested an unsupported content type in Accept header: */*
qgisserver_1  | 1099 - 10.193.23.169 - - [22/Nov/2021:20:37:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 254 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
qgisserver_1  | 20:37:16 WARNING Landing Page[81]: QGIS_SERVER_LANDING_PAGE_PROJECTS_DIRECTORIES empty path: skipping.
qgisserver_1  | 20:37:16 WARNING Landing Page[81]: QGIS_SERVER_LANDING_PAGE_PROJECTS_PG_CONNECTIONS empty connection: skipping.
qgisserver_1  | 1390 - 10.193.23.169 - - [22/Nov/2021:20:37:16 +0000] "GET /index.json HTTP/1.1" 200 557 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
```

This is the definition of the `qgisserver` docker service:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  ...
  qgisserver:
    image: "camptocamp/qgis-server:3.22"
    environment:
      - QGIS_PROJECT_FILE=/etc/qgisserver/my_qgis_project.qgs
      - PGSERVICEFILE=/etc/qgisserver/pg_service.conf
      - QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL=1
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./my_qgis_projects:/etc/qgisserver
```

There is not much documentation on the [docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/camptocamp/qgis-server) for that image.

What could the source of that problem be and how to solve it?

Here is the documentation: https://github.com/camptocamp/docker-qgis-server
I played around it for a while without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: the timeout was a direct consequence of my naive omission to open an SSH tunnel to the database:

```bsh
$ ssh -f -N -L 5432:127.0.0.1:5432 user@server
```

(adapt URL, ports and credentials to your environment)

Comment: If there is direct `5432/TCP` connection available from QGIS server to the database machine called `server`, then using `PGSERVICEFILE` (the `pg_service.conf` file) should allow you to get rid of the tunnel.

Not that you need it but I just guess whether does the `"camptocamp/qgis-server:3.22"` image supports this env-var.